# How can I get the years months lapsed difference from a certain date with powershell custom date?

Tags: powershell

I cannot get the time difference from a certain date using Powershell like below:

```
$Date = '11/12/2001'
(New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-Date -Date $Date) -End (Get-Date)).ToString("'yyyy' Years 'MM' Months 'dd' Days 'hh' Hours 'mm' Minutes 'ss' Seconds'")
```

### Error:

```
Exception calling "ToString" with "1" argument(s): "Input string was not in a correct format." 
At line:2 char:1 
+ (New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-Date -Date $Date) -End (Get-Date)).ToString ...
```

Why I cannot get the Years and Months elapsed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you even creating the TimeSpan manually?  If you subtract a [DateTime] object from another from another PowerShell will return a System.TimeSpan instance.

Example:

```
$Date1 = Get-Date "8/1/2020 4:00 PM"
$Date2 = Get-Date

$Date2 - $Date1
```

I know a general principal is to stick with cmdlets where we can but one has to admit this is way cleaner.

There are standard format strings for TimeSpan objects documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-timespan-format-strings) and custom format strings documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings) .

I must admit though I don't fully understand this topic, and these formats seems to come out similar looking.

Here are a few examples on top of [Olaf's fine answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63743343/4749264)

```
$TS = ($date2 - $date1)
"{0:dd} Days, {0:hh} Hours, {0:mm} Minutes, {0:ss} Seconds" -f $TS
```

A kludge-y approach:

```
$TS.ToString( "%d\D%h\H%m\M%s\S" ).Replace("D", " Days, " ).Replace("H", " Hours, " ).Replace("M", " Minutes, ").Replace( "S", " Seconds")
```

Another fairly hideous thing you can do:

```
$TS.ToString('dd\ \d\a\y\s\,\ hh\ \H\o\u\r\s\ mm\ \M\i\n\u\t\e\s\ ss\ \S\e\c\o\n\d\s\')
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the notation for dates. A timespan object does have this I think. You could use something like this:

```
$Date = '11/12/2001'
$TS =  New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-Date -Date $Date) -End (Get-Date)
"{0} days, {1} hours, {2} minutes, {3} seconds" -f  $TS.Days, $TS.Hours, $TS.Minutes, $TS.Seconds
```

Output `$TS` as it is to see what you can use. ;-)

```
$TS
```